# Как прочитать имя файла на китайском в delphi

Tags: delphi, файлы, unicode, интернационализация

Возникла задача - прочитать имя файла, состоящее из китайских символов.

Как это сделать, надо ли изменять язык Windows на китайский, что вообще использовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Delphi в версиях до 2009 поддержка Unicode в VCL очень ограниченна. Поэтому желательный вариант - это обновиться до версии 2009 и использовать возможности Delphi. Если это невозможно, то нужно прямо работать с функциями Windows API для Unicode вида APIFuncW (W на конце).

Comment: Спасибо. А проект Delphi 7 в Delphi 2009 запустится?

Comment: после конвертирования и некоторых плясок (зависящих от количества сторонних компонент и работы со строками в коде) - да

Answer (score 1):

В версиях Delphi до 2009 для хранения юникодных строк и работы с ними есть типы 'WideString', 'WideChar' и 'PWideChar'. Можно использовать их для работы с юникодным WinAPI, чтобы открыть файл с именем на китайском.